# SQL server stored proc "Procedure or function expects parameter, which was not supplied."

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I've recently changed a couple of functions recently while debugging a cte query (have gotten help here). I just changed a couple of functions.. this got my query to work.. but now when my C# client code calls those functions through stored procs for my program logic, I get the error "Procedure or function 'DateTimeOfNextAvailableDataRun' expects parameter '@NextDateTime', which was not supplied.
" Maybe multiple values are coming back?

Here's the function in its current form:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()
    RETURNS date
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(hour, 18, MIN(TradingDate)) AS TrDate
    FROM tblTradingDays
    WHERE (DATEADD(hour, 18, TradingDate) > dbo.LatestDataDownloadDate()))
END
```

And the stored proc that invokes it:

```
ALTER PROC DateTimeOfNextAvailableDataRun
    @NextDateTime DateTime2 OUTPUT
AS
    SELECT @NextDateTime = dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()
```

And lastly my client code, which did run before the change:

```
public DateTime DateTimeOfNxtAvailableDataRun()
            {
                DateTime dateTimeOfNxtAvailableDataRun;

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DateTimeOfNextAvailableDataRun", this.sqlConnection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dateTimeOfNxtAvailableDataRun = (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }

                return dateTimeOfNxtAvailableDataRun;
            }
```

Any takers? Again, the functions work within my sql server query (see recent posts by me) but now the calling code disagrees..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the body of the `using` statement and add an output parameter before executing the command.

```
var outputParameter = new SqlParameter { 
    ParameterName = "@NextDateTime",
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};
cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParameters);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
return (DateTime)outputParameter.Value;
```

Comment: I thought that obvious but I was running without it I'm sure. Maybe not in my hours of late night trial and error... thx.

Comment: Can't I just return the value? Much more intuitive than output paramaters for such a simple function..

Comment: You cannot "return" a non-integer value from a stored procedure. You can, however, just `SELECT` the value in the stored procedure like "SELECT dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()" and simply use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` and cast the result back to `DateTime`

Comment: OK thx... it looks like I still need an output parameter that way, correct?

Comment: No, you won't. In that case, you should modify the procedure and make it parameterless.

Comment: Can you humor me, and give me the syntax for that method, using your suggestion of "SELECT dbo." ? The code still chokes and wants a parameter..

Comment: `ALTER PROC DateTimeOfNextAvailableDataRun AS SELECT dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()`
and `using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("DateTimeOfNextAvailableDataRun", sqlConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) return (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: Hey sorry to ask for spoon- feeding here... I'm new to this as of this week... I'm making progress per your suggestion, using parameters, and at the moment it errors on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); "String[0]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0."